# Expected 2D array when try to predict new sentences

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

After I built a model, I would like now to check the results with new data.
I have used the following

```
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

X_train= np.asarray(X_train)
y_train= np.asarray(y_train)
X_test = np.asarray(X_test)

score_log = clf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(['Hello World'])
```

using the logistic regression model.

Unfortunately I have got

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['Hello World'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

When I have tried to use

```
top=['Hello World'].reshape(-1,1)
```

and `['Hello World'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)`

I have got this new error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Could you please explain me how to check new sentences in my model?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use the wrong way to generate the prediction. Normally, you will need to embed `'Hello World'` to a 2D vector space by using a particular transformer. The example is as follow:

```
# transform text to vector
corpus = ['Hello World']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
word_vectors = X.toarray()

# Apply your prediction model with word_vectors below
## CODE
```

For more information about CountVectorizer, you can read at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

For more information about the entire pipeline, you can read at https://www.kaggle.com/catris25/logistic-regression-with-countvectorizer